# Find out which customers made purchases over $75 within a 10 day period

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
purchase
---------------------
customer      VARCHAR
cost          DECIMAL
purchase_date DATE
```

I would like to get a list of all the customers that made a total purchase of $75 or more within a 10 day period.

The following SQL gives me this amount within the past 10 days:

```
SELECT customer
FROM purchase 
WHERE purchase_date >= (CURRENT_DATE - 10)
GROUP BY customer
HAVING sum(cost) >= 75;
```

How can I extend this query to include any 10 day period?

Postgresql already has a function called generate_series that can give me all the purchase_dates from the first to the last:

```
SELECT generate_series((select min(purchase_date) from purchase), 
                       (select max(purchase_date) from purchase),
                       '1 day') as generated_date;
```

Now I need to modify the above query to use the days from the generated series. This is where I am stuck. How do I run the first query for each date in the second query substituting `purchase_date >= (CURRENT_DATE - 10)` with `purchase_date >= (generated_date - 10)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by jpw's answer joining purchase with generate_series gives me the same result but much faster:

```
SELECT distinct customer 
from generate_series((select min(date) from purchase), 
                     (select max(date) from purchase),
                     '1 day') as generated_date, 
     LATERAL(
            SELECT customer
            FROM purchase
            where date 
            BETWEEN (generated_date - INTERVAL '10 day') AND generated_date
            GROUP BY customer
            having SUM(cost) >= 75
        ) p 
ORDER BY customer;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use a lateral join like below. I haven't been able to test it though.

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table y1
LEFT JOIN LATERAL(
    SELECT Customer, SUM(Cost) Cost
    FROM your_table y2
    WHERE y1.Customer = y2.Customer 
      AND y2.purchase_date 
          BETWEEN y1.purchase_date - INTERVAL '10 Day' AND y1.purchase_date
    GROUP BY Customer
    ) AS lat ON TRUE
WHERE lat.cost >= 75
ORDER BY Customer;
```

This should return those rows where the sum of the cost for the preceding 10 days is >= 75.

Comment: Also it seems like somewhat of a slow query.

Comment: Not sure if you can do this with a cross join; a correlated sub query should work, but that's pretty much what the lateral join is I think. Performance is probably bound to be bad as you're executing a sum for the preceding 10 rows for every row, which is a pretty expensive operation. There might be better ways to do this with Postgresql but I'm not that familiar with PG to come up with anything better.

Comment: I'll probably need to cache this, this gives me the right result but the page takes over 8 seconds to load...

Comment: Instead of self joining, joining generate_series makes this much faster!

Comment: @Ramin Ah cool. Like I said, I couldn't test it so I guess there's plenty of room for improvement.